# run command in Python3.X

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to work on this code following the book, but the output is nothing. So I am not sure what is happening?[shown output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuZUD.png), thanks.

```
import os
cmd = 'pwd'
fp = os.popen(cmd)
res = fp.read()
stat = fp.close()
print(res)
```

Comment: I use python 3.9.4 and it returns the current path with Jupyter notebook. You can also put this code in a python file and run it with `python your_code.py`, that will do. Also, you can use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to do the same thing. `import subprocess; subprocess.check_output('pwd')`.

Comment: I use "import subprocess; subprocess.check_output('pwd')", the code have error "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified." I'm not sure because of the Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from `os.popen()`: Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete.

Use the `subprocess` module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section.

for more information [os.popen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen)
and [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Comment: I have faced another profblem when I use 'subprocess.' there is error "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified." My operating system is Window and run in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: This error is because i run above command in a window shell, but do not specify the `shell=True` argument in subprocess module’s run method. After i add `shell=True` argument in subprocess module’s run method, it runs successfully like below. for example this `subprocess.run(["Directory", "/p"])`  replace `ret = subprocess.run(["Directory", "/p"], shell=True)`

Comment: Thank you. I got it! I appreciated your time and your help :)